# Cancan Ability during the creation of new objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have the following:

```
User has_many Listings
Listing has_many Offers
```

Pretty basic. A user can publish listings and other users can make offers on those listings.

On each Listing View, you can see a description of the listing, and also a list of all of the offers it has received. Also, on this same view, there is a form which lets users make an offer on this Listing.

Of course, if I am looking at my own Listing, I do not want to be able to make an Offer. So, I'm trying to add a restriction on the Offer's create method, to only allow access to it if it is from a User different from the one that posted this Listing. In my Ability class, it would be something like:

```
can :create, Offer if listing.user != user
```

This doesn't work since `listing` is not defined anywhere. This method will be called when a user is viewing a certain `listing`, so, how can I pass this current Listing to the cancan method to effectively check this restriction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the CanCan ability check until after the point at which you've created the new offer.  E.g.

```
#listing.rb
load_and_authorize_resource :except => :create

def create
    @offer = #whatever it is you want to do
    authorize! :create, @offer

end
```